# signalr sending messages several times issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub, sqldependency

I am new to SignalR and I implemented Signalr (asp.net MVC, sql dependency)
I need to update only the client with a certain databaseID(master_table.masterid)

I notice that first few times of updating the records, it works fine but if I leave the app on for a few minutes and then update the records, it keeps on calling "update-messages" function several times and then stops working.

Can anyone please suggest what could be wrong with this code?

This is the code in my main page(this is the index page which has the another layout page)

```
<div style="overflow:auto;" class="panel-body">
@Html.Action("SignalRTesterPartialView", "MasterTester")
</div>
```

This is my partial view page JS code

```
    $(function () {
    var dialog, form
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.

    var notifications = $.connection.messagesHub;
    //debugger;
    //Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    notifications.client.updateMessages = function (hName) {
    alert(hName + "in update message");
    getoneMessages(hName)
    notifications.server.leaveGroup(hName);
    };
    // Start the connection.

    $.connection.hub.qs = { 'System_Name': '2' }
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    var hostName =getUrlVars()["System_Name"];
    //alert('connected');
    notifications.server.joinGroup(hostName);
    }).fail(function (e) {
    alert(e);
    });
    });

    function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') +   1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
   }

function getoneMessages(hName) {
   var tbl = $('#selectable');
   //alert('mesgID=' + mesgID)
   //var tbl = $('#selectable');
   $.ajax({
   url: '/MasterTester/SignalRTesterPartialView',
   cache: false,
   contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'html'
   }).success(function (result) {
   //alert(result);
   tbl.empty().append(result);
   }).error(function (exception) {
   //alert('failed= ' + exception);
   });
   }

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
$.connection.hub.stop();
};
```

This is my SQL dependency code

```
public PartialViewResult TesterView()
{
commandText = "select various fields where MasterKeyId=" + masterID;"
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(regularConnectionString))
{
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
{
connection.Open();

var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

// NOTE: You have to execute the command, or the notification will never fire.
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
}
}
```

This is my hub code

```
public static void SendMessages(string hName)
{
IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagesHub>();
hostName = hName;
context.Clients.Group(hostName).updateMessages(hName);
}

public Task leaveGroup(string hName)
{
return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, hName);
}

public Task joinGroup(string hName)
{
return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, hName);
}

public Task OnDisconnected(IRequest request, string mID)
{
return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, request.QueryString["System_Name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your db is in auto_close mode.

```
select name from master.sys.databases where is_auto_close_on = 1
```

If it is you should disable it.

Comment: No, I don't think it is enabled since the above sql returned 0 rows.I think the problem is with the connection.start or stop or joihning and leaving rthe groups in the right time sicne the update message is getting fired several times.